# How to display error details within blazor-error-ui element in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

For my Blazor WebAssembly app, I would like to be able to display details of the error (message, stacktrace) within the blazor-error-ui element.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

The trouble with the blazor-error-ui is they are on the HTML index page which is not a Blazor component.

As a workaround you could create your own Blazor component and use Cascading Values to display the errors. Please see link https://nightbaker.github.io/gitflow/azure/piplines/2020/01/22/blazor-error-component/

You would of course have to handle the errors with a try catch block and populate the error message and stack trace into your custom Blazor component.

Seems a lot of work when all you have to do is press F12 and view the same in the developer tools.

Comment: Our requirement is, if possible, to capture any error from any component.

Comment: If Blazor is able to toggle the visibility of the component, then it should be able to send the error details along with that toggling. Maybe this is a feature request for the Blazor team.

Comment: Please see the following link: https://nightbaker.github.io/gitflow/azure/piplines/2020/01/22/blazor-error-component/ unfortunately this still means you have to put a try catch around everything that might cause an exception.  Maybe the Blazor team should be asked to provide a way of showing any unhandled exceptions directly.

Comment: @Mark3308 what about unhandled exceptions? Im getting one all i get in the cream notice at the bottom?